# Can not compile wine on Centos 7 with 64

Tags: x86-64, centos7, wine

I trying to compile wine-0.9.1 on CentOS7. 
The configure finish okay, I run

```
 ./configure --enable-win64
```

When I run:

```
'make depend && make'
```

I get:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode'
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libwine_unicode.so.1 -Wl,--version-script=./wine_unicode.map casemap.o collation.o compose.o cptable.o fold.o mbtowc.o sortkey.o string.o utf8.o wctomb.o wctype.o c_037.o c_424.o c_437.o c_500.o c_737.o c_775.o c_850.o c_852.o c_855.o c_856.o c_857.o c_860.o c_861.o c_862.o c_863.o c_864.o c_865.o c_866.o c_869.o c_874.o c_875.o c_878.o c_932.o c_936.o c_949.o c_950.o c_1006.o c_1026.o c_1250.o c_1251.o c_1252.o c_1253.o c_1254.o c_1255.o c_1256.o c_1257.o c_1258.o c_10000.o c_10006.o c_10007.o c_10029.o c_10079.o c_10081.o c_20866.o c_20932.o c_21866.o c_28591.o c_28592.o c_28593.o c_28594.o c_28595.o c_28596.o c_28597.o c_28598.o c_28599.o c_28600.o c_28603.o c_28604.o c_28605.o c_28606.o     -o libwine_unicode.so.1
compose.o: In function `lstrcpynW':
/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode/../../include/winbase.h:2029: multiple definition of `lstrcpynW'
casemap.o:/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode/../../include/winbase.h:2029: first defined here
compose.o: In function `lstrcpynA':
/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode/../../include/winbase.h:2044: multiple definition of `lstrcpynA'
casemap.o:/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode/../../include/winbase.h:2044: first defined here
compose.o: In function `lstrlenW':
...
/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode/../../include/winbase.h:2092: multiple definition of `lstrcatA'
casemap.o:/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode/../../include/winbase.h:2092: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libwine_unicode.so.1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/../wine-0.9.1/libs/unicode'
make[1]: *** [unicode] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/../wine-0.9.1/libs'
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

How can I find what cause the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You're asking this on Stack Overflow (instead of superuser or unit/linux.SE), as a programming question, so you're trying to debug this yourself?  I'd suggest finding both definitions.  IDK why the linker error only seems to mention one definition.

Comment: yes I trying to debug it...

Comment: when I bring wine from https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-wine-on-centos it compile okay. Tnx.